# How to accumulate number of hours where a certain criteria is met for a Deedle series?

Tags: c#, time-series, deedle

I have a problem that I am currently solving a bit quick and dirty in Deedle, but I am obviously not solving it in the most efficient way.

The input data consists of some dumps with quite high frequent data on the format `<DateTime,double>`, with somewhat random sample intervals (varying between ~20ms and 10 minutes).

I want to calculate a new time series with the time (number of hours) where one or more of these data series satisfy certain conditions. Example: calculate uptime hours based on a power consumption higher than a given limit.

Now I have solved it quite roughly by first generate a series with 0 or 1 depending on if the value meets the criteria, then interpolating that series into a series with one value per minute, then for each 60-item chunk (i.e. for every hour) calulate the mean value, and then finally use expanding sum to get the accumulated value.

Code for generating test samples:

```
// Generate some example data:
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

var rnd = new Random();
var builder = new SeriesBuilder<DateTime,double>();
var loopTime = startTime;
while (loopTime < endTime) {
    builder.Add(loopTime, rnd.NextDouble()*4000d);
    loopTime = loopTime.AddSeconds(20d + rnd.NextDouble()*100d);
}

// Accumulation criteria:
double loRange = 2000;
double hiRange = 7000;

var dataSeries = builder.Series;

var dataSeries = builder.Series;

Console.WriteLine("dataSeries contains {0} elements:", dataSeries.KeyCount);
dataSeries.Print();
```

Outputs (something like):

```
dataSeries contains 900819 elements:
11.11.2013 11:01:24 -> 1621.68410123404 
11.11.2013 11:02:55 -> 416.716641009188 
11.11.2013 11:04:19 -> 1018.02155422886 
11.11.2013 11:05:18 -> 1765.56553028783 
11.11.2013 11:05:53 -> 3282.86457587167 
11.11.2013 11:06:57 -> 1879.04809875369 
11.11.2013 11:08:43 -> 3259.35750792704 
11.11.2013 11:09:46 -> 3782.27438767547 
11.11.2013 11:11:00 -> 1874.62322873744 
11.11.2013 11:12:16 -> 3709.64714871237 
11.11.2013 11:14:07 -> 3370.90207607062 
11.11.2013 11:15:34 -> 696.881372806095 
11.11.2013 11:17:28 -> 1225.02550539795 
11.11.2013 11:18:51 -> 1002.21338356017 
11.11.2013 11:19:13 -> 1485.16262578087 
...                 -> ...              
11.11.2015 10:45:20 -> 2453.45101247237 
11.11.2015 10:45:53 -> 1941.55326762309 
11.11.2015 10:47:23 -> 2050.54933673262 
11.11.2015 10:48:52 -> 1520.56644368943 
11.11.2015 10:50:38 -> 918.71558358833  
11.11.2015 10:52:36 -> 1060.91481310358 
11.11.2015 10:53:00 -> 2246.04634672685 
11.11.2015 10:53:31 -> 532.949643457751 
11.11.2015 10:55:21 -> 3282.98021447052 
11.11.2015 10:56:10 -> 2528.27528795613 
11.11.2015 10:57:32 -> 288.598969713132 
11.11.2015 10:57:53 -> 3936.26360964787 
11.11.2015 10:58:31 -> 2164.81776450054 
11.11.2015 10:59:39 -> 2257.33688392552 
11.11.2015 11:00:53 -> 2500.25997427304
```

Then the accummulation code:

```
// Make new series that holds 1 if criteria is met and 0 if not:
var rawRunningStatus = dataSeries.Select(item => item.Value > loRange && item.Value <= hiRange ? 1d : 0d);

// Generate a set of timestamps for minute-interpolation:
var allMinuteTimestamps = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (int)endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes)
    .Select(offset => startTime.AddMinutes(offset))
    .ToArray();

var interpolatedPerMinute = rawRunningStatus.InterpolateLinear(allMinuteTimestamps, (t1, t2) => (double)(t2 - t1).Ticks);

var runningStatusPerHour = interpolatedPerMinute.Chunk(60).Select(h => h.Value.Mean());

var hourlyTotal = Stats.expandingSum(runningStatusPerHour);

// Finally, downsample to daily values:
var total = hourlyTotal.Aggregate(
                Aggregation.ChunkWhile<DateTime>((d1, d2) => d1.Date == d2.Date),
                chunk => KeyValue.Create(chunk.Data.FirstKey().Date, OptionalValue.Create(chunk.Data.LastValue())));
total.Print();
```

Outputs something like:

```
11.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 4.99771656325056 
12.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 16.9026901059461 
13.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 28.4346829644089 
14.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 40.1625579749059 
15.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 51.5181959176441 
16.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 63.3829428344991 
17.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 75.9086422691164 
18.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 87.8313912439796 
19.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 99.5987951841397 
20.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 111.948344483972 
21.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 124.061910225063 
22.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 136.246391792296 
23.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 148.16014209087  
24.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 160.765062418469 
25.11.2013 00:00:00 -> 173.016057085084 
...                 -> ...              
28.10.2015 00:00:00 -> 8598.97006880338 
29.10.2015 00:00:00 -> 8610.78890255565 
30.10.2015 00:00:00 -> 8623.3606308629  
31.10.2015 00:00:00 -> 8635.00161576886 
01.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8647.01037016803 
02.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8659.29864453147 
03.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8670.50290643172 
04.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8682.60815854525 
05.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8694.33936107482 
06.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8705.96593473042 
07.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8717.99715996875 
08.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8730.08276786404 
09.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8741.60045331112 
10.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8753.78545457176 
11.11.2015 00:00:00 -> 8761.26739180859
```

I am quite sure this can be solved in a better way, both with respect to accuracy and execution speed, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around how to do it yet, nor find any aggregation methods that are operating on the Key rather than the value part of the series. Any suggestions?

Comment: Once you have all the filtered times, you can use `Select` to convert to an operational value (`TimeSpan` or `double` or whatever) and then simply `Sum()`

Comment: @SimpleVar I am afraid I don't understand what you mean by filtered times. And wouldn't sum just return a single scalar value? I need a new series (to be shown as a graph in a web app somewhere else).

Comment: I have completely misunderstood your question, nevermind.